# Howto Update virtual host folder in Webview2?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, webview2

I am using wpf with the New webview2 panel.

I want to show local PDFs in the webview2. I Set up an virtual host
"./www/test.pdf" - >
https://locale.example/test.pdf
folder it works fine.

During the process I overwrite. ./www/test.pdf but it Do Not refresh in the view. Also reload and clear and Re add the virtual Host folder Do Not work.

Has someone an idea?

Or an other approach?

Thank you in advance

#### Edit:

I set up the the Virtual Host Folder with ./www not ./www/test.pdf